# RESTful web service, PUTting an unnamed resource?

Tags: rest

I have a back-end service that creates unique identifiers for resources.

The general idea is that resources are saved and versioned, so you can perform:
`GET http://service/sales/targets/7818181919/latest`
or 
`GET http://service/sales/targets/7818181919/4 for version 4`, and so on.

My question is about the most correct way to upload these resources in the first place.

How about:
`PUT http://service/sales/targets/` returning `303 See other /service/sales/targets/`

It seems a little wrong as you should PUT and GET from exactly the same place using a resource-oriented interface, but I can't think of a better option.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the Location header when you POST or PUT the resource. The target for the POST should be the appropriate 'container' resource (http://service/sales/targets/ in your case)

See [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) for more details on the HTTP Headers. I've quoted the relevant section below. Hope that helps ...

> #### 14.30 Location
>
> The Location response-header field is
>   used to redirect the recipient to a
>   location other than the Request-URI
>   for completion of the request or
>   identification of a new resource.
>
> For
>   201 (Created) responses, the Location
>   is that of the new resource which was
>   created by the request. For 3xx
>   responses, the location SHOULD
>   indicate the server's preferred URI
>   for automatic redirection to the
>   resource.
>
>
>  The field value consists of
>   a single absolute URI.
>
> ```
>    Location       = "Location" ":" absoluteURI
> ```
>
> An example is:
>
> ```
>    Location: http://www.w3.org/pub/WWW/People.html
> ```

Chris

Answer (score 3):

If you create a resource where you don't know yet the exact URI, then use `POST` against the "collection resource" (in your case http://service/sales/targets) and return the new URI in the response `Location` header. This can be compared to the factory pattern in OOP.

Alternatively you can provide a resource that generates unique identifiers. This allows your clients to `GET` an unique identifier first and then use `PUT` against an URI using the identifier. The downside is that you have to maintain a list of all unique identifiers that have been served so far, no matter if they have really been used or not.